# .NET Core 2 and Font Awesome. How to copy webfonts from node_modules to wwwroot on build?

Tags: asp.net-core, npm, font-awesome

I'm trying to figure out how to install Font Awesome via npm into my ASP.NET CORE 2 web project.

Using npm to download Font Awesome, I've updated my package.json file like so: `"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "5.4.2"`

I'm able to add the CSS no problem to my bundleconfig.json file:

```
{
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/styles/forms.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css",
      "node_modules/timepicker/dist/jquery.timepicker.css",
      "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": false,
      "renameLocals": false,
      "adjustRelativePaths": false
    }
},
```

That works and the Font Awesome CSS is bundled correctly.  The bundled css file now lives at:

`[MySite.Web]\wwwroot\styles\forms.css`

And the bundled css in forms.css is looking for the Font Awesome fonts like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("../webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot");
```

However, the fonts don't work because I need the folder:

`[MySite.Web]\node_modules\@fortawesome\fontawesome-free\webfonts`

In my wwwroot directory like so:

`[MySite.Web]\wwwroot\webfonts`

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 (Version 15.8.5)

So my question is how in Visual Studio when I build the Web project do I copy the webfonts folder from node_modules to wwwroot?  Is that even the right approach?

Comment: Did you ever succeeded in solving this? I'm having the exact same issue with a .NET Core 3.1 web application. When the fonts are needed they are requested through "mysite/node_modules/@fortawesome/..." while that location obviously doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few approaches you could use. On the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/less-sass-fa?view=aspnetcore-2.1#font-awesome), their first recommendation is to include the cdn version of the styles file globally. You would do this by inserting `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">` in your main layout file(obviously you could replace the `4.3.0` version with whatever is latest. Following this, you would remove the font-awesome npm package from your `package.json` and from your `bundleconfig.json`.

If you didn't want to do this, wanted to keep the npm package and copy the necessary files, you could copy the files you are interested in through an npm script. To accomplish this, you would create another script in your `package.json` file that would contain the logic to copy the font-awesome files you need into `wwwroot`. I think how to do that might be beyond the scope of this question, but there are a number of npm packages that could help with this. [copyfiles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles) is one such package, but there are others as well.

You could then have Visual Studio invoke this script every time your project builds.

You could do this one of two ways:
Right click on the project file in Visual Studio and choose option `Edit {ProjectName}.csproj` and then add the following items into the xml file that gets displayed.

```
  <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="npm run {NPM_SCRIPT_NAME}" />
  </Target>
```

Alternatively you could right click on the project file in Visual Studio and choose the `Properties` option.

You will be shown the following screen.[image: {NPM_SCRIPT_NAME}]
Go to the `Build Events` tab and enter `npm run {NPM_SCRIPT_NAME}` as seen in the image.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have been using the Font Awesome CDN link, but I would prefer to not depend on a third-party link.  Since it is available via npm that would be my preferred route.  I was hoping for a simple slam dunk solution for relocating the fonts folder, but you've confirmed what I thought; there isn't a quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this code to your csproj file causes the **webfonts**, **sprites**, and **svgs** folders to be copied to wwwroot when the project builds. Of course, you may need to adjust the input and output paths (eg. my input paths are under fontawesome-pro).

```
<!-- Copy the Font Awesome folders to wwwroot -->
<Target Name="CopyFontAwesomeFolders" AfterTargets="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
        <sprites   Include="$(ProjectDir)\node_modules\@fortawesome\fontawesome-pro\sprites\*.*" />
        <webfonts  Include="$(ProjectDir)\node_modules\@fortawesome\fontawesome-pro\webfonts\*.*" />
        <svgs      Include="$(ProjectDir)\node_modules\@fortawesome\fontawesome-pro\svgs\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(sprites)"  DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)\wwwroot\sprites"  SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(webfonts)" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)\wwwroot\webfonts" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(svgs)"     DestinationFiles ="@(svgs->'$(ProjectDir)\wwwroot\svgs\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
</Target>
```